# Why TCP Reset sent on receving packets with sequence number < next expected sequence number

Tags: sockets, tcp

[RST,ACK] is sent to the client after series of data exchanges. Just before [RST, ACK], server received packets with sequence number < next expected sequence number.

Please observe seq-no:4082885727. Went over kernel tcp code but not able to figure-out why reset was sent. Please explain this behaviour.

```
5415657    2014-07-02 01:58:04.690551    10.20.172.219    10.20.5.20    TCP   
60    9920 > 54889 [ACK] Seq=4714727 Ack=4082885727 Win=3840 Len=0

5415658    2014-07-02 01:58:04.690557    10.20.5.20    10.20.172.219    TCP   
1490    [TCP Retransmission] 54889 > 9920 [ACK] Seq=4082885727 Ack=4714727
Win=3840 Len=1436

5415659    2014-07-02 01:58:04.690561    10.20.5.20    10.20.172.219    TCP   
1490    [TCP Retransmission] 54889 > 9920 [ACK] Seq=4082887163 Ack=4714727
Win=3840 Len=1436

5415660    2014-07-02 01:58:04.690564    10.20.5.20    10.20.172.219    TCP   
1490    [TCP Retransmission] 54889 > 9920 [ACK] Seq=4082888599 Ack=4714727
Win=3840 Len=1436

5415661    2014-07-02 01:58:05.183135    10.20.5.20    10.20.172.219    TCP   
1490    [TCP Retransmission] 54889 > 9920 [ACK] Seq=4082885727 Ack=4714727
Win=3840 Len=1436

5415662    2014-07-02 01:58:06.167146    10.20.5.20    10.20.172.219    TCP   
1490    [TCP Retransmission] 54889 > 9920 [ACK] Seq=4082885727 Ack=4714727
Win=3840 Len=1436

5415663    2014-07-02 01:58:08.135187    10.20.5.20    10.20.172.219    TCP   
1490    [TCP Retransmission] 54889 > 9920 [ACK] Seq=4082885727 Ack=4714727
Win=3840 Len=1436

5415664    2014-07-02 01:58:12.071222    10.20.5.20    10.20.172.219    TCP   
1490    [TCP Retransmission] 54889 > 9920 [ACK] Seq=4082885727 Ack=4714727
Win=3840 Len=1436

5415665    2014-07-02 01:58:19.943328    10.20.5.20    10.20.172.219    TCP   
1490    [TCP Retransmission] 54889 > 9920 [ACK] Seq=4082885727 Ack=4714727
Win=3840 Len=1436

5415666    2014-07-02 01:58:19.943608    10.20.172.219    10.20.5.20    TCP   
60    9920 > 54889 [RST, ACK] Seq=4714727 Ack=4082887163 Win=3840 Len=0
```

Thanks,
Srinivas.

Comment: This could be a keepalive packet.

Comment: My query is why reset is sent to client, if it's keep alive then it should have sent only ack?

Comment: They're probably not keepalive packets. They are too close together. I doubt that these packets themselves provoked the RESET. It's all strange. You would probably need to know what both peer applications were doing.